# Help diagnosing wifi connection issue (Debian)

Tags: debian, wifi

I am having wifi problems, and I don't even know how to begin diagnosing the issue.  My problem is: my wifi works fine on some floors of my office building and doesn't work on other floors.  But, in both cases, NetworkManager is able to connect to a wifi access point and give me an IP (the same IP in both cases), and running route -n gives me the same output.  But, on the floors where things don't work, I can't ping/traceroute any other IP addresses.

How should I go about figuring out what's going on?

(I'm running Debian 9.1.)

Answer (score 1):

The sounds like the issue is at the access point, not your laptop.  You are probably connecting to different APs on different floors and the APs are configured differently.  For example, my network will allow you to connect to it with the passphrase, but will not allow you to pass traffic unless I enable your MAC.  You are going to have to work with the admin of the APs to resolve the problem.

Comment: I work at a university and have registered my MAC, so there should be no issue with that.  My mobile device, which I registered the same way, works fine on all floors.

Comment: The MAC was only an example.  It could be the firewall, routing tables, any number of things.  You are trying to troubleshoot a problem with only half of the information.  Looking at the AP should give some information on why  it is not routing correctly.  That said, can you ping the AP or gateway itself?  What error does traceroute give you?